# How to hide a plugin's title via Typoscript when rendering with css_styled_content

Tags: typo3, typoscript

This is probably very basic, but I'm stuck.

In TYPO3 6.1.x with tx_news, I have configured the news detail view to appear on the same page as the list view as taught on http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/latest/Main/Tutorial/IntegrationWithTs/Index.html

Also, I have pulled in the news'header as h1 as such

```
temp.h1 = COA
temp.h1 {

    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        value = <h1>{page:title}</h1>
        insertData = 1
    }

    10 = RECORDS
    10 {
        if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        dontCheckPid = 1
        tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
        source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        source.intval = 1
        conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
        conf.tx_news_domain_model_news {
            field = title
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }
        wrap =  <h1>|</h1>
    }

}
```

**What I couldn't solve yet** is that the plugin element has a title (in the regular "header" field). I need to display this header only in the list, but **hide that plugin's header field in detail view**.

How / where can I do that via page TS?

This is probably not even in the plugin, but in css_styled_content?
Something like this...

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
        plugin.tx_news.stdheader >
[else]
```

But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plugin is always using this prototype object:

```
tt_content.list
```

Therefore you could delete the header of this object like that

```
tt_content.list.10 >
```

But if you have other plugins on the same page, their headers would also be deleted. So that would be a bad idea.

I would suggest you use the header_layout field. By default it has an entry called "Hidden" that will hide the header of your plugin. If you don't have it, check the Page TypoScript configuration. You can add own items by using:

```
 TCEFORM.tt_content.headerLayout.addItems.99 = My Header Layout
```

Then you can then define the rendering of your own layouts in

```
lib.stdheader.10
```

(it's a CASE object)

Comment: And it isn't possible to do something like page.10.marks.NEWSCONTENT.list.10 >? to target this only to the desired object?

Comment: About header_layout: I'm using that field extensively already. Does your solution imply that the user picks that "hidden" value from header_layout?

Comment: You can replace the header definition with a CASE and render it depending on some list_type field. Or you just append an .if and check for the same field (only one condition supported then).